# No module named pyinotify

Tags: python, pynotify

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mitmf.py", line 29, in <module>
    import core.responder.settings as settings
  File "/home/hacklab/Downloads/MITMf-master/MITMf/core/responder/settings.py", line 24, in <module>
    from core.configwatcher import ConfigWatcher
  File "/home/hacklab/Downloads/MITMf-master/MITMf/core/configwatcher.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pyinotify
ImportError: No module named pyinotify
```

I cannot open mitmf. I wonder if I should use another program?

Comment: What is "mitmf"? Why did you expect that you can import a module called `pynotify`?

Comment: did you do `pip install` it? like `pip install pynotify`

Comment: Yep i did already pip install but it still same

Comment: What do you get when you do `pip list` in a terminal? This often happens when you are using the wrong environment.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have installed the correct package. There are two packages available, `pynotify` and `pyinotify`. Please note the additional letter `i` in the second one.

The error message says that `pyinotify` is missing.

So check the output of `pip list` (or maybe `pip3 list`, depending on your environment).